# Data truncated for column 'column name' at row 1

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

This is my model class attribute

```
@Column(name = "createdate")  
@Type(type="long_timestamp")  
private Date creationDate;
```

This is my Type definition

```
@TypeDef(  
name="long_timestamp",  
typeClass = com.x.LongTimestampType.class  
),
```

Please refer my LongTimestampType.java

```
public class LongTimestampType extends TimestampType {


    @Override
    public String objectToSQLString(Date value, Dialect dialect)
            throws Exception {
        return "" + ((Date) value).getTime();
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(ResultSet rs, String index) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        return new Date(rs.getLong(index));
    }

    @Override
    public void set(PreparedStatement ps, Date value, int index, SessionImplementor sessionImplementor)  throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        System.out.println("set Date as BIGINT into Prepared Statement :: " + ((Date)value).getTime());
        ps.setLong(index, ((Date)value).getTime());
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "long_timestamp";
    }

    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] { Types.BIGINT };
    }

   /* public int sqlTypes() {
        return Types.BIGINT;
    }*/
}
```

This is my mySql table column

```
createdate  bigint(20) NULL
```

My java code to save this object is

```
entityManager.persist(object);
```

My Problem is, When i trying to save Object into table it'll throw: `java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncated for column 'createdate' at row 1`
Even i set **null** to createDate also. Please give solution to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

`public String objectToSQLString(Date value, Dialect dialect)`

should be

`public String objectToSQLString(Object value, Dialect dialect)`

otherwise the method is not overwritten correctly

Comment: I have used hibernate 3.6, Above solution is related with hibernate 3.5. So still i'm in problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with

```
createdate  bigint(20) NULL
```

You should declare this as `datetime`

Try to

```
alter table table1 modify createdate datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your column

```
createdate as varchar(20)
```